# calling jquery AJAX dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The following code is not working for me and I don't know why...

this is my js code:

```
var getEventsFunctionScript = document.createElement('script');
getEventsFunctionScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
getEventsFunctionScript.innerHTML = "function getEvents(){$.ajax({url:'myPHP_file.php',type:'post',data:{'ajaxData':'1'},success:function(response){alert('AJAX executed!!');}});}";
w.document.body.appendChild(getEventsFunctionScript);
```

this us my php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['ajaxData'])) {
    exit;
}
```

My problem is that this is not working, Ajax is never executed (I never see the alert)

could someone give any idea about why this is not working?

thank you very much

Comment: What's the `w.document` in your last line?  Are you trying to append this script to another window?

Comment: Your script concept works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/z8phL/

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're trying to append this script to another window.  If so, you have to create the script element in that window's document, not in the current document.  `var getEventsFunctionScript = w.document.createElement('script');`.  That other window will also have to be the same origin as the current window for the browser to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function afterwards:

```
getEventsFunctionScript.innerHTML = "function getEvents() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myPHP_file.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'ajaxData': '1'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('AJAX executed!!');
        }
    });
}
getEvents();";
```